# What is the sum of all complex integers?

Tags: complex-analysis, divergent-series, zeta-functions

In line with

$$\zeta(-1)=-1/12$$
Could we, by considering

$$f(s)=\sum_{a,b\in\mathbb Z,\;(a,b)\neq(0,0)}\frac{1}{(a+bi)^{s}}$$
Evaluate the sum of all complex integers?

Comment: Yes. The result is $-\frac{1}{12}-i \frac{1}{12}.$

Comment: I doubt it but thanks for the guess

Comment: That's actually little more than a joke. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: I suppose this is equivalent to proving a Zeta reflection formula-like identity (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/598871/39568)) for $f(s)$.

Comment: Which values of $s$ should one consider? For non real integer values of $s$, there is no general definition of $(a+bi)^s$.

Comment: On the other hand, note that $\sum\limits_{(a,b)}|a+bi|^{-s}$ converges absolutely for every complex $s$ such that $\Re s\gt1$.

Comment: A good point on the non integer bit. I would define for general complex z $ z^s=\exp(s\ln(z))$. Where exp and log are define by taylor series and thus single valued.

Comment: Perhaps make it explicit in the question that you're looking for the analytic continuation of $f(s)$, not just a special case of the analytic continuation.

Comment: Nice problem. From a naive evalutation of the $s=-1$ sum it seems like $f(-1) = (1+i)\zeta(0)\zeta(-1) = \frac{1}{24}(1+i)$ would be a likely value.

Comment: How did you arrive at this?

Comment: It was just a loose conjecture. With $f(-1) = \sum_a \sum_b a+ib = (1+i)(\sum_a a^1) (\sum_b b^0) = (1+i)\zeta(0)\zeta(-1)$. btw this is considering the sum over positive $a,b$ only!

Comment: Except that the logarithm cannot be defined by its Taylor series (and *which* Taylor series by the way?).

Comment: It can for this problem. We can use log(1-x). It is like saying $1^{1/2}\ne 1$ because it is multivalued. Yes, it $is$, but nonetheless we can force it to be single valued.

Comment: In other words, one knows how to define $(a+ib)^s$ when $|a+bi-1|\lt1$. Not many points with integer coordinates in there, I am afraid... :-)

Comment: You would do it in terms of $(a+bi)^s = Re^{si\theta}$

Comment: Then you would have to specify how to determine theta... Right, since you make me repeat the same basic point over and over again and do not wish to listen, I shall stop here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to restrict to positive integers only since...

$$f(s) = \sum_{a>0,b>0} \frac{1}{(a+ib)^s} + \sum_{a>0,b<0} \frac{1}{(a+ib)^s} + \sum_{a<0,b>0} \frac{1}{(a+ib)^s} \\+ \sum_{a<0,b<0} \frac{1}{(a+ib)^s} + \sum_{a=0,b\in Z}\frac{1}{(ib)^s} + \sum_{a\in Z,b=0} \frac{1}{a^s}$$

giving

$$f(s) = (1 + (-1)^s)\left[\left(\sum_{a>0,b>0} \frac{1}{(a+ib)^s} + \frac{1}{(a-ib)^s}\right) + \zeta(s)(1+i^s)\right]$$

So $f(-1)$ (meaning the analytical continuation) will be $0$ (unless the analytical continuation of $\sum_{a>0,b>0} \frac{1}{(a+ib)^s} + ...$ has a simple pole at $s=-1$).

The same happens if one consideres the sum of all integers:

$$g(s) = \sum_{n\in Z, n\not= 0} \frac{1}{n^s} = (1 + (-1)^s)\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^s} = \zeta(s)(1 + (-1)^s)$$

so the 'sum of all integers' are zero.

Comment: Don't forget the pairs $(a,b)$ where one is zero and the other isn't.

Comment: @seaturtles Thanks, I missed that one:) Will change it!

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure how to go about proving it in any form of notation, but if we consider the real number axis from -x to +x, and the imaginary axis from -iy to +iy, then all the complex integers will be plotted as iy against x.  Since there are no limits to the size of either real or imaginary parts and given that they may only be integers.  I would have thought that the sum of all the complex integers would be zero.  Mainly because the sum of all imaginary numbers from -iy to +iy is zero, and all the real numbers from -x to +x is zero.  Am I missing something?

I see what you are saying, so 1+(1-1-1)+(1-1-1)...=-∞
But 1-(1-(1-1-1))-(1-(1-1-1))...=+∞

I'm not sure that eventually if all the combinations of number series is included in the argument a situation would arise where the net result is asymmetric.

Thank you Winther, I don't know if everyone will agree with you, but I do. But I'm beggining to see now that with complex numbers the problem may well be different.

Comment: You are missing that the sum of a series that is not absolutely convergent can be made to be anything at all, by suitable rearrangement of the terms. The situation is the same as with Grandi's series, $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i = 1-1+1-1+\ldots = 0+0+0+\ldots = 0$ and also $= 1-(1-1)-(1-1)-\ldots = 1-0-0-\ldots = 1$.

Comment: Or similarly consider just the “sum of the integers”. You claim that $\sum_{i\in\Bbb Z} i = 0$, because you have grouped it as $0 + (1 + -1) + (2+-2) + \ldots$.  But if you group it instead as $(0+1) + (-1 + 2) + (-2 + 3) + \ldots = 1+1+1+\ldots$ the sum is infinite.

Comment: Yeh, I see where you are coming from, basically -1-(-1) two minuses  become a +, but 1+(+1) still a plus.

Comment: The other way of looking at it is that 0 can either be considered as a number or not, for example, the Fibonacci sequence can start at 0 but only becomes sequensial with the rules once the first +1.